# Getting rss content using for loop PHP

Tags: php

I try to scrap an feed using below PHP code

```
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $item_content=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('content:encoded')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link
  . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
  echo ("<br>");
  echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
}
```

but I got an error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` in the line of $item_content, why? This is the feed link http://www.rotikaya.com/feed/

Comment: The error message would help

Comment: Which error you get? Does the item with index 0 exists?

Comment: @bish Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @ub3rst4r Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

The error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` means that you try to access an object that does not exists. Check the line of the error message and your code and make sure that a) the feedobject you want to read does exists and b) the index of it you want to read the data from with your `$i` variable.

The using of `var_dump($variable)` should help you debugging your code and to find out which object / index is not existing.

Comment: I solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346628/retrieving-rss-feed-with-tag-contentencoded