# getting smaller <content:encoded> than it should

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I'm trying to get RSS feed with tag , but the  always gets reduced to a small part of the text continued by "...".
I already checked [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346628/retrieving-rss-feed-with-tag-contentencoded) but I got no results as I expected.
This is the feed I'm trying to parse:

https://bus237d201smartphones.wordpress.com/feed/

And this is my code:

```
function resolveFile($file_or_url) {
    if (!preg_match('|^https?:|', $file_or_url))
        $feed_uri = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/shared/xml/'. $file_or_url;
    else
        $feed_uri = $file_or_url;

    return $feed_uri;
}

$file_or_url='https://bus237d201smartphones.wordpress.com/feed/';
$file_or_url = resolveFile($file_or_url);
if (!($x = simplexml_load_file($file_or_url)))
    return;

foreach ($x->channel->item as $item)
{
    $content  = $item->children("content", true);;
    echo("<br>");
    echo("content <br>");
    print_r($content);
    $e_encoded     = $content->encoded;
    echo("<br>");
    echo("encoded <br>");
    print_r($e_encoded);
}
```

This is browser output:

```
content 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [encoded] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) 
encoded 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) 
    Google made the Android operating system for all kinds
    of handheld devices (Smartphones and PC Table...
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to get content of element `<content:encoded>` where content is namespace `xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"`, you can do it with this code:

```
<?php

function resolveFile($file_or_url) {
    if (!preg_match('|^https?:|', $file_or_url))
        $feed_uri = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/shared/xml/'. $file_or_url;
    else
        $feed_uri = $file_or_url;

    return $feed_uri;
}

$file_or_url='https://bus237d201smartphones.wordpress.com/feed/';
$file_or_url = resolveFile($file_or_url);
if (!($x = simplexml_load_file($file_or_url)))
    return;

foreach ( $x->getNameSpaces( true ) as $key => $children ) {
    $$key = $x->children($children);
}

foreach ($x->channel->item as $item)
{
    $childrenContent = $item->children('http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/');
    $encodedContent  = $childrenContent->encoded->__toString();
    echo("<br>");
    echo("encoded <br>");
    print_r($encodedContent);
}
```